# How to create a custom DateTime in php?

Tags: php, datetime

Hi here I have a scenario that i have two strings in two variables,

```
$a = '2017-03-09';
$b = '16:00';
```

these are like date part and time part of `datetime` in `php`
i want to join these part and create a `datetime`
and want to perform `diff` operation , for example i have created this `datetime` as a variable `$custom_datetime`

my output should be as

```
$interval = $custom_datetime->diff(date());
die($interval->format('%H:%I:%s'));
```

this operation should give a proper time difference but i am unable to make this `$custom_datetime`

Comment: thanks @PaulCrovella for response i have tried as in scnario `$a = $date_part` and `$b = $hour_part`

Comment: `$custom_date = new DateTime($day_part.' '.$hour_part);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is an example of what you are trying to achieve :**

```
 $day_part = '2017-03-09';
 $hour_part = '16:00';
 $format = 'Y-m-d H:i';
 $datetime = DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $day_part.' '.$hour_part);
 echo "Format: $format; " . $datetime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "\n";

 $interval = $datetime->diff(new DateTime());

 echo "<br>";
 echo "Interval :".$interval->format('%H:%I:%s');
```

[The documentation is right here](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php);
[Check this link to run the code;](https://eval.in/764461)

Good Luck

Comment: yes dear coder that what is i am trying but nothing is printing on my side, good knowledge dear

Comment: @MudassarZahid, change the formatting from $format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s'; to $format = 'Y-m-d H:i';

Answer (score 1):

Use the  DateTime::createFromFormat()   static  method  to  create  a    DateTime   instance    with
a   date    and time    string  that    uses    a   custom  format. This    method’s    first   argument    is  the date
and time    string  format. The second  argument    is  the date    and time    string  that    uses    said
format :

```
$a = '2017-03-09';
$b = '16:00';

$datetime   =   DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d H:i', $a.$b);
print_r($datetime);
```

The  DateTime::createFromFormat()   static  method  accepts the same    date    and time
formats as  the  date()     function.   Valid   date    and time    formats are available   at
http://php.net/manual/datetime.createfromformat.php.